# play youtube video in uiwebview without iphone video player

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I want to play youtube video in `UIWebView` only.

And don't want that iPhone video player plays video.

I want to implement this in swift

```html
var url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/yUEFauIpR40"

var htmlUrl = "<html><head><body style=\"(margin:0)\"><embed id=\"yt\" src=\"\(url)\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"width=\"\(560)\" height=\"\(315)\"></embed> </body></html>"

webView.loadHTMLString(url, baseURL: nil)
```

It plays the video in video player instead `UIWebView`.

Comment: Should you not be calling: `webView.loadHTMLString(htmlUrl, baseURL: nil)`. Looks like you are passing url instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlUrl, baseURL: nil)
```

The above code solves your problem. Rory has the correct answer, you need to pass the `htmlUrl`.